# Create a view from 2 tables with multiple subquery

Tags: mysql, view

I have two tables

```
table song

|   ID  |   TITLE   |   AUTOR   |   CODE    |
|   1   |   title_1 |   autor_1 |   123     |
|   2   |   title_2 |   autor_2 |   1332    |
|   3   |   title_3 |   autor_3 |   3434    |

table playlist

|   ID  |   DATE        |   EVENT   |
|   1   |   2020-05-01  |   123     |
|   2   |   2020-05-02  |   3434    |
|   3   |   2020-09-23  |   123     |
```

now I create a VIEW because table are very large

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View_song
AS
select c.id, c.title, c.autor, c.code,
( select
count(p.event) from playlist p
where p.event =  c.code
) as total_counter
from song c
```

So I have a VIEW with the total songs + the column total_counter

```
|   ID  |   TITLE   |   AUTOR   |   CODE    |   total_counter   |  
|   1   |   title_1 |   autor_1 |   123     |       2           |
|   2   |   title_2 |   autor_2 |   1332    |       0           |
|   3   |   title_3 |   autor_3 |   3434    |       0           |
```

I want to add a column to the VIEW so I want to have a more column with today_counter

```
|   ID  |   TITLE   |   AUTOR   |   CODE    |   total_counter   |  today_counter    |
|   1   |   title_1 |   autor_1 |   123     |       2           |       0           |
|   2   |   title_2 |   autor_2 |   1332    |       0           |       0           |
|   3   |   title_3 |   autor_3 |   3434    |       0           |       1           |
```

I try this query

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View_song
AS
select c.id, c.title, c.autor, c.code,
( select
count(p.event) from playlist p
where p.event =  c.code
) as total_counter
( select
count(p.event) from playlist p
where p.event =  c.code AND date = CURDATE()
) as today_counter
from song c
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: The logic of creating views because 'tables are large' escapes me

Comment: I have to use it with datatables framework

Comment: That's a different reason (if it's really a reason)

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` to these calculations in single go.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW View_song
AS

SELECT 
    c.id, c.title, c.author, c.code, 
    COUNT(p.`event`) AS total_counter,
    SUM(IF(p.`date` = CURDATE(), 1, 0)) AS today_counter
FROM song c
LEFT JOIN playlist p ON c.`code` = p.`event`
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Add index on `date`, `code` and `event` to make it faster.

Also in your query, you're missing comma after `total_counter`.

Comment: Hi @Jitendra, the LEFT JOIN is very slow, past about 5 minutes I have no responses. I think the subqueries are more fast

Comment: Left join is used to include songs which are not present in any playlist, if that is not a concern, you can use inner join too.

Comment: You are missing a comma after total_counter in your query. You can modify your query and can also try again

Comment: Hi, it works, thanks, but it is not very efficient: Affected rows: 0, Time: 251.267000s